# Get All Bi-Weekly dates of year in Java

Tags: java

I want to calculate bi weekly dates of a year. So I should get 2 dates per month.

I have tired it so far -

```
private static void getAllBiWeeks() {

        int lastYear = java.time.Year.now().getValue() - 1;
        int currentYear = java.time.Year.now().getValue();
        int nextYear = java.time.Year.now().getValue() + 1;

        System.out.println("lastYear - " + lastYear);
        System.out.println("currentYear - " + currentYear);
        System.out.println("nextYear - " + nextYear);

        LocalDate lastYearDate = LocalDate.of(lastYear, 12, 01);
        LocalDate currentYearFirstDate = LocalDate.of(currentYear, 01, 01);
        LocalDate currentYearLastDate = LocalDate.of(currentYear, 12, 31);
        LocalDate nextYearFirstDate = LocalDate.of(nextYear, 01, 01);

        System.out.println("lastYearDate - " + lastYearDate);
        System.out.println("currentYearFirstDate - " + currentYearFirstDate);
        System.out.println("nextYearFirstDate - " + nextYearFirstDate);

        LocalDate lastYearLastDate = LocalDate.of(lastYear, 12, 31);
        LocalDate lastYearLast15Days = lastYearLastDate.minusWeeks(2);

        System.out.println("lastYearLast15Days - " + lastYearLast15Days);

        System.out.println(lastYearLast15Days.isBefore(nextYearFirstDate));

        for (LocalDate date = currentYearFirstDate; date.isBefore(currentYearLastDate); date = date.plusWeeks(2)) {
            System.out.println(date);
        }
    }
```

But it is not giving correct dates, it gives following output -

```
lastYear - 2018
currentYear - 2019
nextYear - 2020
lastYearDate - 2018-12-01
currentYearFirstDate - 2019-01-01
nextYearFirstDate - 2020-01-01
lastYearLast15Days - 2018-12-17
true
2019-01-01
2019-01-15
2019-01-29
2019-02-12
2019-02-26
2019-03-12
2019-03-26
2019-04-09
2019-04-23
2019-05-07
2019-05-21
2019-06-04
2019-06-18
2019-07-02
2019-07-16
2019-07-30
2019-08-13
2019-08-27
2019-09-10
2019-09-24
2019-10-08
2019-10-22
2019-11-05
2019-11-19
2019-12-03
2019-12-17
```

How can I get dates like this -

```
2019-01-01
2019-01-16
2019-02-01
2019-02-16
.
.
```

Comment: Why would you *expect* those dates? I would expect the dates you're currently getting: starting at a particular date, then getting two weeks later, then two weeks later etc. Why do you expect February 1st after January 15th? Why do you expect February 28th after February 1st? (That's nearly 4 weeks later!) If you can describe what you're aiming for more clearly, it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Corrected expected answer in question.Thanks. I need two dates in each month, those are starting of each bi-week. So 2019-01-01, 2019-01-16, 2019-02-01, 2019-02-16 so on.

Comment: I am using `date.plusWeeks(2)` but it is not giving what I am expecting.

Comment: What if a month is having 31 days? What is the second date you are expecting?

Comment: @PrashantZombade Actually I need 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-15 and 2019-01-16 to
2019-01-31 . So I am trying to find bi weekly dates

Comment: It sounds like you want "the first of the month and then the 16th of the month" in each case. The code is doing exactly what you're *asking* it to at the moment - January 29th plus two weeks *is* February 12th - but that's not what you actually want. What you're describing isn't what I'd call "biweekly dates" - your current *output* is what I'd call biweekly. You'll end up with 24 dates in a year, whereas biweekly you'd end up with 26.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I should use 1st and 16th and make use of Last date of each month.

Comment: @NinadPingale: What do you mean by "and make use of last date of each month"? Currently your requirements are *very* unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to calculate bi weekly dates of a year. So I should get 2 dates per month.

No, not necessarily. There are 52 weeks in a year (plus a bit) but only 12 months. Biweekly - every other week - would give you 26 or 27 dates per year, whereas "2 dates per month" would give you 24 dates per year.

If you want the 1st and 16th (not 15th?) for each month of the year, I'd suggest just doing that in a loop:

```
for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year, month, 1);
    System.out.println(LocalDate.of(year, month, 16);
}
```

It sounds like that will give you the output that you're looking for - but you should be aware that's *not* what most people would understand to be "biweekly".

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<LocalDate> getAllBiWeeks(int year) {
    List<LocalDate> res = new ArrayList<>(12 * 2);

    for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
        res.add(LocalDate.of(year, month, 1));
        res.add(LocalDate.of(year, month, 16));
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others having same requirement in future-

Using this

```
for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
            int lastDayOfMonth = YearMonth.of(currentYear, month).lengthOfMonth();
            System.out.println(LocalDate.of(currentYear, month, 1)+" To "+LocalDate.of(currentYear, month, 15)+" , "+LocalDate.of(currentYear, month, 16)+" To "+LocalDate.of(currentYear, month, lastDayOfMonth));
}
```

I got what I needed -

```
2019-01-01 To 2019-01-15 , 2019-01-16 To 2019-01-31
2019-02-01 To 2019-02-15 , 2019-02-16 To 2019-02-28
2019-03-01 To 2019-03-15 , 2019-03-16 To 2019-03-31
2019-04-01 To 2019-04-15 , 2019-04-16 To 2019-04-30
2019-05-01 To 2019-05-15 , 2019-05-16 To 2019-05-31
2019-06-01 To 2019-06-15 , 2019-06-16 To 2019-06-30
2019-07-01 To 2019-07-15 , 2019-07-16 To 2019-07-31
2019-08-01 To 2019-08-15 , 2019-08-16 To 2019-08-31
2019-09-01 To 2019-09-15 , 2019-09-16 To 2019-09-30
2019-10-01 To 2019-10-15 , 2019-10-16 To 2019-10-31
2019-11-01 To 2019-11-15 , 2019-11-16 To 2019-11-30
2019-12-01 To 2019-12-15 , 2019-12-16 To 2019-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastDayOfMonth()` method from `TemporalAdjusters`. Example:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth;

public class NewClass2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate currentYearFirstDate =  LocalDate.of(2019, 01, 01);
        LocalDate currentYearLastDate  =  LocalDate.of(2019, 12, 31);
        for (LocalDate date = currentYearFirstDate; date.isBefore(currentYearLastDate);date = date.plusMonths(1)) { 
            LocalDate firstHalfStart = date;
            LocalDate firstHalfEnd   = date.plusDays(14);
            LocalDate secondHalfStart = date.plusDays(15);
            LocalDate secondHalfEnd   = date.with(lastDayOfMonth());
            System.out.println(firstHalfStart + " to " + firstHalfEnd + " , " + secondHalfStart + " to " + secondHalfEnd);
        }
    }

}
```